# Laravel Eloquent how to get all parents

Tags: laravel, eloquent, parent

I have relation like this:

[DB relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FD4r.png)

I have a code in my model that retrieves me just one parent:

```
    public function AllParents()

   {
      return $this->belongsToMany($this, 'parent', 'product_id', 'parent_id')
            ->select('parent', 'name');
   }
```

I get it in my controller like this:

```
private function product(Product $product)
{
    return $product->Product()
        ->with('AllParents')
        ->get();
}
```

Finally I need data like this:

> Product1/Product_2/Product_3

I think I need a loop, but how to do it in Eloquent?

Comment: I think instead of extra table you can add parent_id to same table . unlesss you have any additional field for it

Comment: is there any error .can you also mention query which you tried

Comment: @John Lobo he can have multiple parents that way.

Comment: I can not edit the database

Comment: Use a `while` loop. `while (! is_null($product->AllParents()))`

Answer (score 0):

Just change relationship. You have mentioned pivot table name wrong one.

```
public function AllParents()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'Product_parent', 'product_id', 'parent_id') ->select('parent', 'name');

}
```

and then you can access

```
\App\Models\Product::with('AllParents')->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Product Model. You have define relationship like this.

```
 public function allParents()
 {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_parents', 'product_id', 'parent_id')->select('name');
 }
```

And, In Controller you can get all the parents with eager loading.

```
 Product::with('allParents')->find($productId);
```

And, In View you can use foreach loop to iterate every parent object.

```
 @foreach ($product->allParents as $parentProduct)
      {{ $parentProduct->name }}
 @endforeach
```

Comment: where did the product_parents came from? same table?

Comment: No, It's not the attribute, It is the pivot table name.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this:
I modified my controller

```
private function product(Product $product)
{
    $allParents = [];
    $parent = null;
    $parent->$product->Product()->with('AllParents')->first()->id;
    while ($parent != null) {
        array_push($allParents, Product::all->find($parent));
        $parent = Product::all()->find($parent) - first();
    }
}
```